# Image resizeing increases noise for CNN

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have images of different sizes (i.e. 50x100, 20x90). At the moment for the input to Convolution Neural Network (CNN) is 28x28, so I just use imresize function in MATLAB to 28x28. But I think that will increase the noise in the image. is there any other to first make the image of equal size then resize it to 28x28?

Comment: I will not increase the noise. How could it do that? Are you using the right term, "noise"? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I am confused. you want to make your images of equal size, then resize to 28x28? isn't that the equal size aimed for? if you want to "resize" your images aliasing might appear as a form of noise. A low-pass filter applied on the images will remove some of that "noise". If that's what you are asking for

Comment: I think you want to make width and height the same before resizing it to avoid stretching the image, for that you would have to crop it or add a black frame to make it equal, then you can resize it.... however it will depend on how are you planning to do the cropping (centered, top, bottom, special feature like faces?) to create a more complete answer

Comment: @api55 well if I add the zero padding at the boundaries to make size equal than it doesn't perform well for the CNN. As some images a horizontally long. I saw a method image wrapping in some article. Any idea how can I do that? or how it works?

Comment: Maybe you mean warping?, you can do it but it will be similar problem, your images may look stretch, skew, etc if you transformed them... you can also crop them (remove extra pixels) until it fits, and try to keep the relevant information... not sure if that may help you

Comment: @api55 is it possible for to give this explanation in an answer with some example to show.. it would be very helpful for me.